# How to count number of unique values in a categorical variable, by groups of multiple columns

Tags: r, group-by, count, summarize

I am having a terrible time figuring out this script. I am working with camera trap data, and have variables for camera name, species, and time of day species was captured on camera (day or night). I want to know for each camera, how many times each species occurred during the day. Ultimately I am looking for a variable, perc.day, of the percent of occurrences during the day for each species for each camera. perc.day would be # of "day" detections / all total detections for each species on each camera. I have been using dplyr and data.table.

Here is a sample of what the data looks like:

```
camera <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C')
species <- c('deer', 'deer', 'deer', 'coyote', 'deer', 'deer', 'deer', 'deer', 'coyote', 'coyote', 'coyote', 'bobcat')
time_cat <- c('day', 'day', 'night', 'day', 'night', 'day', 'day', 'day', 'night', 'day', 'night', 'night')

data <- data.frame(camera, species, time_cat)
```

And what I need it to look like:

```
camera <- c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C')
species <- c('deer', 'coyote', 'deer', 'deer', 'coyote', 'bobcat')
total.detections <- c('3', '1', '3', '1', '3', '1')
perc.day <- c('0.667', '0', '0.667', '100', '0.333', '0')

data.final <- data.frame(camera, species, total.detections, perc.day)
```

This code works up to the detections variable, but at a loss for how to get the perc.day variable

```
data.final <- 
  data %>%
  group_by(camera, species) %>%
  summarize(total.detections = n())
```

Thank you for any help or advice.

Comment: What is the rule to calculate "total.detections"?

Comment: total.detections is the number of times each species was captured on each camera, so for camera A there was a total 2 deer and 1 coyote detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A final `mutate` and `ungroup` on top of your original solution does the trick:

```r
data %>%
  group_by(camera, species) %>%
  summarize(total.detections = n(),
            day_count = sum(time_cat == "day")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(per.day = day_count / total.detections)

# # A tibble: 6 × 5
#   camera species total.detections day_count per.day
#   <chr>  <chr>              <int>     <int>   <dbl>
# 1 A      coyote                 1         1   1    
# 2 A      deer                   3         2   0.667
# 3 B      deer                   3         2   0.667
# 4 C      bobcat                 1         0   0    
# 5 C      coyote                 3         1   0.333
# 6 C      deer                   1         1   1
```

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. That's not quite what I am looking for, in your script perc.day =  the ratio each species was captured on each camera. I need perc.day to be the percent of each species detections during the day vs the night, taken from the time_cat column. I noticed my sample code was a bit wonky and updated it. In the "what I need it to look like" data frame, the 0.667 in row 1 means that of all deer detections on camera A, 0.667 of them where during the day. Hope this helps and thank you so much!

Comment: Ah I see, let me know if my edits work!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you are looking for those `camera` and `species`" only when `time_cat` is `day`, that would be better to split the code a little bit:

```
camera <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C')
species <- c('deer', 'deer', 'deer', 'coyote', 'deer', 'deer', 'deer', 'deer', 'coyote', 'coyote', 'coyote', 'bobcat')
time_cat <- c('day', 'day', 'night', 'day', 'night', 'day', 'day', 'day', 'night', 'day', 'night', 'night')

data <- data.frame(camera, species, time_cat)

data$total.detections<-1
data$perc.day<-0
data[data$time_cat=="day","perc.day"]<-1

aggregate(total.detections~camera+species,data,sum) %>%
  mutate(perc.day=aggregate(perc.day~camera+species,data=data,sum)$perc.day/total.detections)


  camera species total.detections  perc.day
1      C  bobcat                1 0.0000000
2      A  coyote                1 1.0000000
3      C  coyote                3 0.3333333
4      A    deer                3 0.6666667
5      B    deer                3 0.6666667
6      C    deer                1 1.0000000
```